# Is there a way to delete a row from an HTML table with user input using Flask (jinja2)?

Tags: jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm new to Flask and programming. I'm creating a simple database using Flask/SQLite. I'm having users enter the data in a form and having that data populate on an HTML table next to the form. I've managed to achieve this. However, I've like to add the ability of a user to delete a row in the table.

I've created a function in my routes.py that I've like to utilize, but I can't find a way to pass user submitted information back to my routes.py function. I've tried using an HTML link but I don't want to pass the user to another URL and back. Is there a way to achieve this?

From routes.py

```
@app.route("/")
@app.route('/interventions', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def interventions():
.....  

    qinter = Interventions.query.all()

    def delete_entry(entry):

        db.session.delete(qinter[(entry-1)])
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('interventions'))
 .....
```

From Interventions.html

.........

```
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Delete?</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Chart #</th>
            <th>Provider</th>
            <th>Pharmacist</th>
            <th>COI</th>
            <th>Accepted?</th>
            <th>Intervention</th>
        </tr          
        {% for q in qinter %}
            <tr>
                <td><<a href="{{ delete_entry(q) }}">delete</a></td>
                <td>{{  q.date  }}</td>
                <td>{{  q.chart  }}</td>
                <td>{{  q.prescriber  }}</td>
                <td>{{  q.pharmacist  }}</td>
                <td>{{  q.category  }}</td>
                <td>{{  q.accepted  }}</td>
                <td>{{  q.intervention  }}</td>
            </tr>
         {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

Comment: Using ajax you can delete, update, add records without reloading page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is some way to communicate from your HTML template to your interventions route that you want to delete a certain row in your database table. To do that you need to add some additional parameters to your route function, like this:

```
@app.route('/interventions', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/interventions/<action>/<item_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def interventions(action=None, item_id=None):

    def delete_entry(entry):

        db.session.delete(entry)
        db.session.commit()


    if request.method == "POST":

        if action == 'delete':

            # Get specific row user wants to delete
            qinter_row_to_delete = Interventions.query.get(item_id)

            # Delete row
            delete_entry(qinter_row_to_delete)

            return redirect(url_for('interventions'))


    elif request.method == "GET":

        qinter = Interventions.query.all()

        # Render template etc...
```

Then from Jinja template make a call to that endpoint to delete the row:

```
<form id="form" action="{{url_for('interventions', action='delete', item_id=q.id)}}" method="POST">
```